# Motorcycle armour: soft vs hard, which best absorbs impacts and why?

Tags: forces

I am a motorcyclist who knows very little about physics :(

Motorcycle jackets and trousers have impact protectors: padded thingies in the impact areas (back, elbows, shoulders, knees, hips) which are meant to protect us in case of an impact, absorbing part of the impact and transferring less force to our fragile bodies; see https://www.d3o.com/products/t5-evo-pro-x/

This British company makes armour which is softish, but hardens on impact:
https://www.d3o.com/what-is-d3o/

My question is: is this a good thing, and why? Wouldn't I want the armour to stay soft, rather than hardening on impact? How does impact absorption differ with hard vs soft materials? Which transfers more force to the body and why?

After all, if I hit a wall, I'd much rather have a soft mattress, not a hard steel plate, softening my impact. Am I missing something?

On motorcycle forums there are mixed opinions on this, but I'd like to understand the physics behind it - single experiences (I came off with this type of armour and I did/didn't hurt myself) mean very little.

Thanks!

PS The site warns me the question appears subjective, but it is not: I am asking how force absorption differs, not who prefers one kind over the other

Comment: I ride too. It isn't just about impact but avoidance of what a skid does too as you must know.  The hard stuff if you will protects the softer stuff meant to absorb and spreads out the impact over a wider area a bit.  You would never just put the shell of a helmet up against your head and feel like it would do much good against impact except to increase that already mentioned surface area.  Now put the liner in and you have protected the absorbing material to do it's job against impact.  Not sure this is a good physics question but it is a good question.

Comment: I up voted because I think it is a question that might  save someone serious damage, but there are specific sites that it might be better for if , you have a look, and that you don't need physics concepts to post on.

Comment: The idea of safety here is to try reducing the impulse in a collision, $F\Delta t = m\Delta v$ so to reduce the amount of force that an object feels on collision we want to increase the amount of time that the collision lasts. When we consider the human body, we are easily scratched up and fragile, especially when we think about the speeds of motorcycle travel. The armor being hard on the outside will protect from scratches and wounds, while a soft inner layer which absorbs shock is ideal beneath the hard exterior - something to reduce he impulse (force) transferred to our bodies.

Comment: Carry your own airbags and cushion (take longer to slow down) any fall.  http://carandbiker.co/motorcycle-airbags-review/

Comment: Let me clarify:  I rely mainly on the outer layer of the jacket (e.g. leather, ) for protection from abrasion; the armour is underneath, and, should the outer fabric be eroded, the armour might provide some abrasion resistance – or it might not, because, with the outer fabric worn through, the armour is more likely to move around during a slide or tumble.
Europe has strict homologation criteria defining how much energy should be absorbed in strictly defined tests (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle_armor#EN1621-1_Armor_for_All_Body_Parts_.28Except_Back.2FSpine.29 ).

Comment: Let me then rephrase the question: if two protectors transmit the same force, as measured by the above test, does it make a difference whether the protector is made of soft or hard material, or of a combination? Can two impacts cause different pain/damage even if the force transmitted (again, as measured above) is the same? 
For example, this competitor of D3O has a protector which is hard on the outside and soft on the inside: https://www.planet-knox.com/product/knox-air-ce-protector-part-45/

Comment: There is a discussion on this motorcycle forum: http://advrider.com/index.php?threads/soft-vs-hard-armour-how-good-is-d3o-which-hardens-on-impact.1136364/ but it mainly reports individual (and statistically irrelevant) experiences, with not much in terms of ‘science’ to back up the various claims.

Answer (score 2):

The ideal case for a motorcycle would be a hard shell with either energy absorbing restraints and harnesses or soft padding. This is the tested paradigm in modern race cars.

A hard shell albeit one designed to absorb huge energies in a crash where calculated sacrifice members of shell will crumple and will act as a safety cage and the harness or padding will reduce the deceleration to a level that delivers a manageable blow to vital organs.
The breaking of a crash into several softer stages is to go through most crashes with no damage and a potential really bad one with less damage.

Another factor is the rider. A good fall even in a fast crash and anticipation of trajectory of body and protecting the head could be the difference. I do powder ski and try to roll into a crash once it is past point of no return. I have practice my portfolio of moves and do not waste time thinking what to do!

Comment: So does this mean that the ideal protection is hard on the outside and soft on the inside, like a helmet? In other words, is it fair to say that, if only the outer part of a D3O protector hardens, leaving the inner part soft, it's good, but if it all hardens, then it's much less good?

Comment: Yes, right. Like a crab, exoskeleton.

Comment: But what if D3O and a softer protector transmit the same force, as measured by the homologation tests referred to above? Would they really be equivalent, or are there other aspects whereby, even if the force transmitted in the tests is the same, one could be better or worse than the other?

Comment: Force could be the same but cushioning will allow vital organs just enough of dampening. Also softer inner layer will give the body a chance to align itself with impact coming from side angle or offset in a way that could concentrate t blow to a small critical area! Many jells do this. I would think a combination of hard shell and soft inner membrane similar to sneakers padding is better.